# How to execute a Bash alias over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
ssh andy@<ip_address> "cat .bash_aliases; sayhello"
```

Here's what happens:

```
alias sayhello="echo hello"
bash: sayhello: command not found
```

---

To be more specific about my problem I'm trying to invoke the command
`"sudo etherwake -i eth0 <mac_address>"` over ssh -- this executes (I think) on my local computer, giving a `sudo: unable to resolve host [blabla]` error.  It seems like any commands that are not standard bash commands are parsed by my local machine.

If that's what's happening, how do I get around it?  If not, what *is* the explanation?

Comment: maybe you can try this? `source .bash_aliases; sayhello`

Comment: @ajreal already did.  no luck.

Comment: what is inside .bash_aliases?

Comment: @ajreal the single line `alias sayhello="echo hello"`

Comment: Can it be the alias commands save as a file then you execute the file?

Comment: @ajreal Obviously! Thanks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general this is **not a good idea** to use aliases in scripts.

Yet I can suggest one way to do it, but bare in mind how unsafe it is.

- It relies on `eval`,
- It reads remote files into the shell context.

Here we go.

```
ssh remote_host "shopt -s expand_aliases ; source ~/.bash_aliases ; eval sayhello"
```

#### Explanation:

1. By default alias expansion is enabled only for interactive shells. To turn it on use `shopt -s` command.
2. You will need to source the aliases into your shell context anyway.
3. Now you are set to use your aliases via the `eval` command.

Answer (score 1):

@ajreal gave a simple solutions in the above comments -- just put what you want to happen in a file, then execute the file.

So I created a file on the host called `sayhello.sh` (containing only the line `echo Hello`), then on my local machine used

`ssh andy@<ip_address> "sh sayhello.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a pretty messed up hack, but it works:

```
$ ssh xxx.xxx.158.40 'source aliases; alias'

alias emacs='emacs -nw'
alias l.='ls -d .*'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias sayhello='echo hello'
alias vi='vim'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'

$ ssh xxx.xxx.158.40 'source aliases; $( alias sayhello | sed -e "s/.$//" -e "s/.*=.//" )'

hello
```

This also works:

```
ssh xxx.xxx.158.40 "source aliases; \$( alias sayhello | cut -d\' -f2 )"
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `alias` is just silly. The `eval` solution isn't elegant either but at least it works in many corner cases where this doesn't.